# cindent is not working in vim

Tags: vim

I am using vim6.3, but `smartindent` and `cindent` is not working at all, even after manually setting them. The `autoindent` does work if I set that manually. I can see that vim is compiled with `cindent` as can be seen with `:version`.
Even `filtype` plugin indent is on.

Any possible reason for this?

Comment: Vim 6.3? The one released in 2004? Where have you been hiding all the time?!

Answer (score 1):

Update your vim to 7.3 (or newer) by:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Compose ~/.vimrc file with:

```
set cindent
set smartindent
set autoindent
```

Try vim now, it will hopefully work.

Comment: but, still 'cindent' and 'smartindent' should work on 6.3 too. Isn't it?

Comment: It must. But earlier, I had similar problem with indentation and syntax highlighting. Update worked. Try it once and let me know. :)

Comment: it is still not working with vim 7.3, i am not sure what's happening.